# Electron: Simplest example to pass variable from JS to HTML, using IPC, Contextbridge and Preload?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, ipcrenderer

I am trying to learn electron, but I'm struggling to understand this basic functionality of IPC.
Already tried from documentation or tutorials but everytime they overcomplicate with complex examples or using other libaries like svelte, typescript etc. Also I don't want to show in console, I want to display directly in HTML page. I know these are basics, but any help is appreciated.
So far I understood that I need:

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

app.whenReady().then(main);

let window;

async function main() {
    window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 100, 
        height: 100,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname + "./preload.js")
        },
    })
    window.on("ready-to-show", window.show);
    window.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "./index.html"));
}

ipcMain.on("GetMyVar", (event, args) => {
    *???*
})
```

**preload.js**

```
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require("electron");

const API = {
    window: {
        GetMyVar: () => ipcRenderer.send("GetMyVar", MyVar)  *???*
    },
}
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("app", API);
```

**renderer.js**

```
const MyVar = "JUSTSHOWUP!";
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
     <body>
          <h1 id='MyVar'>???</h1>
     </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electron [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) is a difficult subject to
grasp without easy to understand examples.

Your `preload.js` script can be written in a number of different ways. In the below code example, I have included two
ways to do this.

`preload-1.js` uses a simplified, easy to understand direct implementation method. That said, for ease of
maintainability and debugging, as your Electron application grows, you will want to split your `preload.js` script up
into smaller individual `preload` scripts. Bearing in mind that you can only load one `preload` script per window
instance, you may have a need to repeat code between `preload` scripts.

`preload-2.js` uses a more flexible white listed channel naming system where you only need to load the one `preload`
script across all created windows. As a result, your `preload` script only performs a single function, to communicate
between your main process and render process(es). Implementation of the sent and received channel names are kept within
your specific code domains.

---

### `main.js` (main process)

No matter which type of `preload` script you use, implementation will be the same within your `main.js` file.

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection.
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload-1.js')
            // preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload-2.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.webContents.send('messageFromMain', 'Message from main..!'); })
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.on('messageToMain', (event, message) => {
    console.log('Message to main: ' + message);
})
```

---

### `preload-1.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main
        messageToMain: (message) => {
            ipcRenderer.send('messageToMain', message)
        },
        // From main to render
        messageFromMain: (message) => {
            ipcRenderer.on('messageFromMain', message)
        }
    });
```

---

### `preload-2.js` (main process)

At the end of this `preload.js` script, I have included a section on how to use it within your main process and render
process(es).

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main
        'send': [
            'messageToMain'
        ],
        // From main to render
        'receive': [
            'messageFromMain'
        ],
        // From render to main and back again
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);

/**
 * Render --> Main
 * ---------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.on('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); })
 *
 * Main --> Render
 * ---------------
 * Main:    windowName.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.receive('channel', (data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Value) --> Render
 * ----------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', (event, data) => { return someMethod(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Promise) --> Render
 * ------------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
 *              return await promiseName(data)
 *                  .then(() => { return result; })
 *          });
 */
```

---

### `index.html` (render process)

To test which form of `preload.js` script you prefer, just comment out one whilst uncommenting the other.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron IPC Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <label for="messageFromMain">Message from Main Process: </label>
            <input type="text" id="messageFromMain" disabled>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div>
            <label for="messageToMain">Message to Main Process: </label>
            <input type="text" id="messageToMain">
            <input type="button" id="send" value="Send">
        </div>

    </body>

    <script>
        let messageFromMain = document.getElementById('messageFromMain');
        let messageToMain = document.getElementById('messageToMain');

        // Message from main (preload-1.js)
        window.ipcRender.messageFromMain((event, message) => {
            messageFromMain.value = message;
        })

        // Message from main (preload-2.js)
        // window.ipcRender.receive('messageFromMain', (message) => {
        //     messageFromMain.value = message;
        // })

        // Message to main
        document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', () => {
            // (preload-1.js)
            window.ipcRender.messageToMain(messageToMain.value);

            // (preload-2.js)
            // window.ipcRender.send('messageToMain', messageToMain.value);
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'll test your examples