# Electron-Angular: Better way for IPC Communication?

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, ipc

## Hi everyone!

At the moment, I'm learning Angular and Electron at work. One of the task required by my supervisor is to send messages between Angular and Electron.

### What I've done so far

When creating the window, I wrote

```
webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration:true,
                contextIsolation:false
            }
```

### What I would like to do

I would like to send the same messages, but with the use of a preload file, just to not expose the entire thing.

Any suggestions? I found nothing related so far.
For context, versions are Angular 15, Electron 24.3 and Node 18.14.

Comment: This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72639227/2627338) may be of help.

Comment: @midnight-coding nope, didn't help. The problem would be solved if I was only on Electron, but those solution won't work in my use case.